# using pivot_longer and facet_wrap

Tags: r

I am trying to create multi-panel plots, and first need to get my data into long form. Currently my data is in wide form and looks like this

```
ID                Geese   Ducks   Crows   Month
<chr>             <int>   <int>   <int>   <chr>
Bob_Jan_2019       21      30       9      Jan
Bob_Feb_2019       18      34       8      Feb
Bob_Jan_2020       14      34       11     Jan
Bob_Feb_2020       25      32       3      Feb
Ken_Jan_2019       24      24       15     Jan
Ken_Feb_2019       20      19       9      Feb
Ken_Jan_2020       17      28       7      Jan
Ken_Feb_2020       14      25       4      Feb
Rick_Jan_2019      21      23       4      Jan
Rick_Feb_2019      15      29       7      Feb
Rick_Jan_2020      19      30       3      Jan
Rick_Feb_2020      22      35       5      Feb
```

I was able to switch to long using

```
data
data_long <- data %>%
  pivot_longer(!data, names_to = "Bird", values_to = "count")
```

Now I am trying to plot this using facet_wrap, but have run into some issues. I've tried...

```
ggplot(data = data_long, aes(x = Month, y = count)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(Bird))
```

Essentially, I'd like to have six plots, faceted by bird type, with Jan and Feb as discrete values on the x-axis, number of birds on y-axis, and six data points on each plot (two for Bob, Ken, Rick). Any suggestions on how I could use facet_wrap for this?

Comment: Try `data_long <- data %>% pivot_longer(-c(ID, Month), names_to = "Bird", values_to = "count")`

Comment: You will probably want to convert `Month` to an ordered factor so it will plot chronologically: see here for an example using `Jan` / `Feb` data: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#creating-factors